# Can't run a java function inside of kotlin

Tags: java, eclipse, kotlin

My java IDE is Eclipse. I can compile both Kotlin and Java projects.
I can also call a kotlin function inside of a java file, and it works, however, when I try to run a java function in a kotlin file, eclipse just keeps outputting the last thing it did, even tho I saved the file.

For example, I had a program that looked like this:

```
fun main() {
    println ( "examplecode" );
}
```

Which worjed.
Then I tried calling the following function from a java file:

```
    public static int addNums( int a , int b ) {
        return a + b;
    }
```

so the code inside the kotlin file looked like this:

```
fun main() {
    var sum: Int = JavaFile.addNums( 12 , 21 );
    println ( sum );
}
```

In IntelliJ it works, however, Eclipse keeps ouputting HelloWorld, even after I save the new program.

Comment: This should work. Maybe you forgot to add an import for `JavaFile`?

Comment: In Eclipse, it may be running a previously compiled version if the current code doesn’t compile

Comment: If the same thing works in IntelliJ, maybe you should click something like "clean and rebuild" in Eclipse to invalidate caches.